# linux sed how to remove parenthesis from extracted output

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I want to extract **10000** from the string

```
echo "some ran string (unique unique 10000) abc 161 xyz 100"
```

and I'm unable to figure how to remove ending **)**. Below is the sed command I tried so far:

```
sed -n -r 's/.*unique(.*) abc .*/\1/p'
```

The output is:

```
 echo "some ran string (unique unique 10000) abc 161 xyz 100" | sed -n -r 's/.*unique(.*) abc .*/\1/p'
 10000)
```

Any suggestion on how to remove ending ) and leading space from this output? thanks.

Comment: `sed -n -r 's/.*unique (.*)\) abc .*/\1/p'` may be

Comment: Is the number `10000` always comes just before `)` ?

Comment: Nice thanks Pls move this to answer.

Comment: Inian, Some number appears just before ). It can be like 28834) too. Rose comment working.

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM  I went ahead accepted hek2mgl answer for more details. Sorry about mis-spelling your name as 'Rose' in previous comment :-) Its well-passed mid-night, lets blame it on that.

Comment: `echo "..." | egrep -o 'unique [0-9]+)' | egrep -o '[0-9]+'`

Comment: @ghoti Or GNU grep: `grep -oP '\d+(?=\))'` :)

Comment: @hek2mgl - ah yes, I always forget about `-P`, because I use FreeBSD for everything. :)  For completeness, some folks might use `pcregrep -o '\d+(?=\))'` :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following `sed` command, which matches the non-space characters right before the closing parenthesis:

```
sed 's/.*\s\([^\s]*\)).*/\1/'
```

It matches:

```
.*        any character zero or more times
\s        a space
\(        begin of capturing group 1
[^\s]*    non space characters zero or more times (the number)
\)        end of capturing group 1
)         ) after the number
.*        any character zero or more time (the remain of the line)
```

Because the `.*` at the begin and end of the pattern it will match the whole line. It replaces it with:

```
\1        The content of capturing group 1 (the number)
```

---

As indicated in the comments, the above version isn't compatible with POSIX because of the `\s` escape sequence (for a whitespace). For a version compatible with POSIX you may just use the literal space:

```
sed 's/.* \([^ ]*\)).*/\1/'
```

or using the `[:space:]` character class:

```
sed 's/.*[[:space:]]\([^[:space:]]*\)).*/\1/'
```

---

Btw, if you have GNU `grep` you can use Perl regexes. Perl regexes support [look-ahead assertions](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444). Like this:

```
grep -oP '\d+(?=\))'
```

Explanation:

```
-o        output the match only, not the whole line that contains the match
-P        Perl compatible regexes. GNU grep only!

\d+       one ore more digits
(?=\))    look-ahead assertion. Means 'previous pattern is followed by a )'
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I'll go ahead accept this.

Comment: @hek2mgl: Makes the answer more better! Appreciate it!

Comment: @hek2mgl - rather than the literal space, you could also use the character class. `sed 's/.* \([^[:space:]]*\)).*/\1/'`

Comment: @ghoti I agree that would be better readable, at least clear and I would use it in a shell script. But it would be `sed 's/.*[[:space:]]\([^[:space:]]*\)).*/\1/'` and I wanted to avoid that the OP feels scary about `sed` needing so many "crazy" characters for a simple `10000`. :)

Comment: @ghoti Anyhow. Added that.

Comment: @hek2mgl - yes, I totally see your point about crazy characters.  On the other hand .. this IS **sed** we're talking about....  :)

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ echo "some ran string (unique unique 10000) abc 161 xyz 100" | 
  awk -v RS=')' '/unique/{print $NF}'

10000
```

Comment: thanks for awk based solution. I'll use it other location, right now I needed 'sed'

Comment: Smart trick! You may even use `NR==1{print $NF}` to make it independent from the `unique` keyword.